# Make reftex-toc work with multiple files

Tags: latex, auctex, reftex-mode

I'm using Emacs 24.5 with AUCTeX and RefTex to edit a multi-file project. It consists of one main file with `%%% TeX-master: t` to mark as master. The 'slave' files all have `%%% TeX-master: main` to link them to the master file.

RefTex can correctly find the bibliography defined on the master file. However `reftex-toc` only works for the master file. On any slave file it shows only entries for that single file.

How can I make `reftex-toc` aware of multiple files so I can quickly jump into other sections of the document defined in other slave files?

Comment: This feature should work out of the box, provided that `TeX-master` is correctly set. In the secondary files, how do you indicate the master file? It must be a **string** with the relative path to the master file, without extension, so it should be `%%% TeX-master: "main"`, with quotes, if the master file resides in the same directory as the secondary files and is called `main.tex`.

Comment: Thank you again giordano. The issue was with the quotes. Adding double quotes around the master file name solved the issue and now I have ```reftex-toc``` working on every project file. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature should work out-of-the-box, provided that `TeX-master` is correctly set.  The format of that variable is described at [`(info "(auctex)Multifile")`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Multifile).  In particular, in the secondary files `TeX-master` should be a string with the relative path to the master file, without extension.  Thus, if your master file is called `main.tex` and resides in the same directory as the secondary files you should have

```latex
%%% TeX-master: "main"
```

with quotes around `main`.

Note that there is a handy function that can help you to insert the right value of `TeX-master`: [`TeX-master-file-ask`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dmaster_002dfile_002dask), bound to <kbd>C-c _</kbd>.

Note also that it's *strongly* suggested to put the line

```lisp
(setq-default TeX-master nil) ; Query for master file.
```

in your init file, so that you'll be always prompted for the master file (just press <kbd>RET</kbd> to select the current file as master file) every time you create a new *TeX file.

While we are at it, add to your init file also the lines

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
```

to enable all the parsing infrastructure that makes AUCTeX great.  All these settings are suggested in the very first lines of the AUCTeX manual.

Comment: [This refines the previous answer. It should have been a comment but I am new and don't have enough points to answer.] The piece above about: "In particular, in the secondary files TeX-master should be a string with the relative path to the master file, without extension." Has not been the case for me. I use absolute path with extension and that works for me. The quotes are of course needed. I create my file local variables segments with org dynamic blocks and in that situations use of the extension and abs path works better. Also, for master files, I use the .mastex instead of .tex. So withou