# AucTeX - insert environment menu command

Tags: auctex

I have a big LaTeX project divided in many files; the `\documentclass` statement and the preamble are in the main file, that in turn includes many (~20) other files, one for every chapter.  One of the statements in the main file is `\usepackage{paralist}`, in order to use the environment `compactdesc`.

Visiting the main file, in the *AucTeX* `LaTeX -> Insert Environment` menu, `compactdesc` is listed; and `M-Enter` inside the environment inserts an `\item` **and** asks for the label of that item.

Visiting one of the included file, the lack of a `\usepackage` causes no inclusion of the `compactdesc` environment in the `LaTeX -> Insert Environment` menu list; and I don't like that.

Giving the command `M-x LaTeX-environment` followed by `compactdesc`, inserts in the file a `\begin{compactdesc}`-`\end{compactdesc}` couple, but `M-Enter` does **not** ask for the item label - and I would like to be able to enter the labels for every \item added.

I have tried with the local variables at the end of the file, inserting the lines

```
% Local Variables:
% mode: latex
% TeX-master: master.tex
% ispell-local-dictionary: "italian"
% End:
```

(where master is the main TeX file); but still `LaTeX -> Insert Environment` does not know about `compactdesc`.

How can I do, to have both 1) the environment `compactdesc` available and 2) AucTeX knowing about items of that environment having a label?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `TeX-master-file` must be a string, this is exactly the same problem as the one reported here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20007/620  A good practice is to add this line to the init file: `(setq-default TeX-master nil)`

Comment: If you confirm your question is essentially answered by the link above we can mark this question as duplicate (the titles are really different, but I think the main problem is the same: wrong setting of `TeX-master-file`).

Comment: BTW, thanks for your theory of errors book `;-)`

Comment: No, my question has not been answered.  Putting the master file name between double quotes (in the local variables at the end of the file) does *not* add any compactenum entry in the list of environments.  BTW, I have found mention of `TeX-master` in the manual, not of `TeX-master-file`; I tried with both version, with the same result.

Comment: Thank you for remembering my book, the work of all my life; happy to hear that has been useful to somebody 8^)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: `TeX-master`.  After you apply the change, you have to revert the buffer, use `C-c C-n` for that

Comment: ... I did that.  I also quitted and restarted emacs, and added to .emacs the lines `(setq-default TeX-master nil)`, `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` and `(setq TeX-auto-save t)`.  If it matters, I have AucTeX 11.88, emacs 24.5 (macports), OS X 10.11.3 .

Comment: As said in my answer to the linked question, the path to the master file should be without extension `;-)`  The best way yo set the master file is using `C-c _`, which is run by default on a new *TeX file when `TeX-master` defaults to nil.  From now on, you'll be asked for the master file every time you create a new file and you won't for sure make mistakes

Comment: I have read and understood your answer; and the master file name **was** without extension.  I confirm that your suggestions do not work.

Comment: Try issuing `C-c C-n` in your master file, and then restart Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the last suggestion did the magic...  So I have to download the master file first and the included file second?  No problem.  Thank you, giordano, for your suggestions and your tolerance.

I experimented a little bit more. I added to the master file the local variable (at the end of the file) `%%% mode: latex` — that did the trick (in addition to the `%%% TeX-master: "master"` local variable in the included files).

Comment: No, I experimented a little bit more.  I added to the master file the local variable (at the end of the file) `%%% mode: latex` - **that** did the trick (in addition to the `%%% TeX-master: "master"` local variable in the included files.  End of the thread.

Comment: So you had to specify the mode in your master file?  If so, it's really strange: Emacs should be able to figure out the mode by itself, that line is just for more safety, but all `.tex` files are opened with AUCTeX, if installed, and it should be the case for you as well, otherwise you couldn't issue `C-c C-n` in your master file.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5671)

Comment: @Drew It's hard to accept an answer when there is none!

Comment: Which “last suggestion” are you talking about? I don't understand why you mention downloading here — what's being downloaded? Please make your answer self-contained. Comments may be removed at any time.

Comment: @Gilles: Uh, that text in my comment was put there automatically by SE. Before you edited this answer it was only a "thank you" - not an answer, and I chose that reason, among the available possibilities, when voting to close it as a low-quality answer.